# Load url by pressing enter key (android)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

im making an android browser, but when i hit enter, it is adding a new line to edittext box, instead of loading the url. Please help me.The source is [here](http://github.com/gtaricsi/lime)

Comment: Please,give all examples in the question.

Comment: Yeah, we're not gonna go searching through your project to find your error, post relevant code/xml/etc that you think will help us solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Key event. Set setOnKeyListener on the edittext and do something like this:

```
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
     //Load url from EditText
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing an [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) interface. For example:

```
// Reference the edit text view.
EditText theEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.theEditText);

// Set editor action listener.
theEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) { // Enter key was pressed.
            // Open link from url.
        }

        // Return true to prevent the edit text from adding a newline from the enter press.
        return false; // Allow the event to propagate, Return true to consume the event.
    }
});
```

The `actionId` will be equal to `EditorInfo.IME_NULL` if the enter key was pressed.

Hope this helps.